# Woocommerce - Checkout error message

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, errors

I'm looking to remove this error message from my checkout process.
When a customer is an existing user the checkout still prompts for this input fields to be filled in when it is already saved.

My thinking is to remove the requirement for these fields, so i do...

I've been able to remove requirements on other input fields, which removes the error message for those input fields, such as first name etc...
e.g...

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields('fields'){
     unset($fields ['billing']['billing_first_name']['required']);
     unset($fields ['billing']['billing_last_name']['required']);     
}
```

I have done this for the following...

```
country
first_name
last_name
company
address_1
address_2
city
state
postcode
```

My main issue is that, I am still getting an error message saying '(!) Please enter an address to continue.'

I am unsure as to what I and missing, in order to remove this error message?

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you in advanced

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try it for address not required .

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'wc_optional_billing_fields', 10, 1 );
function wc_optional_billing_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['billing_address_1']['required'] = false;
    $address_fields['billing_address_2']['required'] = false;
    return $address_fields;
}
```